# Select top 2 records from each Category

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have 3 tables:

- Products: id, Name
- ProductPrices: id, ProductId, PriceListId, Value, AddDateTime
- PriceLists: id, Title

i can add multiple values for each product in ProductPrices with ProductId and PriceListId

now i want to select from ProductPrices with product id, but not all of them, top 2 values from each Pricelist for current product.

How can i do that?

i wrote this code: but it return all of prices

```
Select PR.PriceListId, PL.Title, PR.id,  PR.ProductId, PR.Value,  PR.AddDateTime
From Products FL left outer join
     ProductPrices PR
     on PR.ProductId = FL.id left outer join
     PriceLists PL
     on PR.PriceListId = PL.id  
group by PR.id , PR.ProductId, PR.Price, PR.AddDateTime, PL.Title , PR.PriceListId 
order by Pr.PriceListId
```

EDIT:

```
    Products:
    id   Name 
    1    Product1 
    2    Product2 

    ProductPrices: 
    id    ProductId    PriceListId    Value    AddDateTime
    1     1            1              XXX      Today
    2     1            1              XXX      YesterDay
    3     1            1              XXX      Older than yesterday
    4     1            2              XXX      Today
    5     1            3              XXX      Today
    6     1            3              XXX      Today
    7     1            3              XXX      YesterDay
    9     2            1              XXX      YesterDay
    11    2            2              XXX      Today
    12    2            3              XXX      Today
    13    2            3              XXX      Today
    14    2            3              XXX      YesterDay

    PriceLists:
    id     Title 
    1      X 
    2      Y
    3      Z

Result from ProductPrices By id should be:

id    ProductId    PriceListId    Value    AddDateTime
1     1            1              XXX      Today
2     1            1              XXX      YesterDay
4     1            2              XXX      Today
5     1            3              XXX      Today
6     1            3              XXX      Today
9     2            1              XXX      YesterDay
11    2            2              XXX      Today
12    2            3              XXX      Today
13    2            3              XXX      Today
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: its Sql Server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, assuming you want the two highest prices per item. If you want lowest, change to "order by value asc" in the row_number function.

```
Select PR.PriceListId, PL.Title, PR.id, PR.ProductId, PR.Value, PR.AddDateTime
From Products FL
left outer join (select * from (
                 select *, row_number() over (order by AddDateTime desc) as row_num 
                 from ProductPrices) 
                 where row_num <= 2) PR 
on PR.ProductId = FL.id
left outer join PriceLists PL on PR.PriceListId = PL.id
group by PR.id, PR.ProductId, PR.Value, PR.AddDateTime, PL.Title, PR.PriceListId 
order by Pr.PriceListId
```

Comment: Correcting: Pr.Price is Pr.Value, And its not working it have errors. i want two top rows by AddDateTime

Comment: @mohammadaghili Edited to take into account your feedback.

Comment: @mohammadaghili This should work, based on your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

It is fun to use `outer apply`:

```
Select PR.PriceListId, PL.Title, PR.id,  PR.ProductId, PR.Value, PR.AddDateTime
From Products FL outer apply
     (select top 2 PR.*
      from ProductPrices PR
      where PR.ProductId = FL.id
      order by PR.value desc  -- presumably you want the "top 2" by value
     ) PL left join
     PriceLists PL
     on PR.PriceListId = PL.id
order by Pr.PriceListId ;
```

I am guessing that the aggregation is no longer needed.

Comment: what i want is not this, i edited my question and new info is added, please look again